Handling a user tapping on a UNNotification Center message and getting the content.userInfo
I am running into an issue that I cannot seem to figure out.  Within my app, I am registering a user notification that fires at a specific time the user selects.  For clarification purposes, I am not trying to determine if my app is being opened from the user tapping, but acquire the user data in the user content.  I need to direct the app to display associated information with the key.  This is working perfectly, it fires on queue.  What I want to do is respond to their tap by displaying the data that was included in the notification:
I am passing in a user data when creating the notification:
    func sendNotification(myDate: Date, myContent: String, myTitle: String, myIdent: Int) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = myTitle
        content.body = myContent
        content.badge = 1
        content.sound = .default
        content.userInfo = ["customData": String(retIdent)]
        ...
}

The retIdent is a numerical key.  I need to be able to respond to that key in a way that makes sense to the user by displaying some info on the screen.
I thought by adding the following to the appDelegate:
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

I added the following code just above return true:
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

and then include the following function in appDelegate:
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
                   @escaping () -> Void) {
       // Get the meeting ID from the original notification.
       let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    
        if response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier == "customData" {
            print(userInfo)
        }
       // Always call the completion handler when done.
       completionHandler()
    }

I have tried testing it, and it never fires the didReceive code.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
If you need more information, I'll post it but I think that's the full code I'm using other than what is being displayed which isn't relevant to my question.
For what it's worth, I did check this link:
iOS push notification: how to detect if the user tapped on notification when the app is in background?, however regardless of whether or not the remote notification is checked it still doesn't fire.  Yes, I added the didReceiveNotification.
Someone attached this to another topic about determining if the app was opened from a user tap, I don't care about that; what I need to know is what is the payload.  I'm not getting anything to fire that says hey here is the content.userInfo.  I'm hoping this makes sense.  Please reopen this topic.
